# Panel division and white marker around markers in MapBox

Tags: html, maps, mapbox

Does anyone have MapBox experience?

I'm trying to implement a personal map with specific markers, complete with pan and zoom features. I was trying to implement [the code from the website](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/pan-vertical-zoom/) that does just this that comes directly from the MapBox website. However, when I implemented in to my own page I got the following:

[image]

As you can see there is a weird paneling effect happening as well as white blocks around the markers. The map is pretty ineffective this way so I was hoping someone out there knew the solution.

Here's the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Pan and vertical zoom</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:500px}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<style>
.ui-control {
  font:bold 12px/28px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  z-index:1000;
  }

.ui-pan {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1000;
  }
  .ui-pan .panner {
    background:#fff;
    color:#404040;
    font-size:9px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:28px;
    height:28px;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-radius:3px;
    }
    .ui-pan .panner:hover { background-color:#f8f8f8; color:#404040; }
    .ui-pan .panner.up    { left:28px; }
    .ui-pan .panner.right { left:58px; top:28px; }
    .ui-pan .panner.down  { left:28px; top:58px; }
    .ui-pan .panner.left  { top:28px; }

.ui-zoombar {
  background:#FFF;
  position:relative;
  top:93px;
  left:28px;
  width:28px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
  .ui-zoombar:hover { background-color:#f8f8f8; }
  .ui-zoombar .handle {
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:26px;
    height:28px;
    background:#404040;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:2px;
    }
    .ui-zoombar .handle:hover { background:#303030; }

</style>

<div class='ui-control'>
  <div id='pan' class='ui-pan'>
    <a href='#' id='up' class='panner up'>&#9650;</a>
    <a href='#' id='right' class='panner right'>&#9654;</a>
    <a href='#' id='down' class='panner down'>&#9660;</a>
    <a href='#' id='left' class='panner left'>&#9664;</a>
  </div>
  <div id='zoom-bar' class='ui-zoombar dragdealer'>
    <div id='handle' class='handle'>0</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='map'> </div>

<!-- If you plan to use this example, download dragdealer from
https://code.google.com/p/dragdealer/ instead of hotlinking it like this -->
<script src='https://dragdealer.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.9.5/dragdealer.js'></script>
<script>
var zooms = 19;
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'tlchang.ikgi2358', {
    zoomControl: false
  })
  .setView([42.0, -3.5], 2);

// Configure Dragdealer to update the map zoom
var zoom_bar = new Dragdealer('zoom-bar', {
    steps: zooms,
    snap: true,
    horizontal: false,
    vertical: true,
    callback: function(x, y) {
        var z = y * (zooms - 1);
        map.setZoom(z);
        handle.innerHTML = z;
    }
});

// Round the zoom value the number looks presentable.
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var z = Math.round(map.getZoom());
    zoom_bar.setValue(0, z / 19);
    handle.innerHTML = z;
});

document.getElementById('left').onclick = function(e)  { e.preventDefault(); map.panBy([-100, 0]); };
document.getElementById('right').onclick = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); map.panBy([100, 0]);  };
document.getElementById('down').onclick = function(e)  { e.preventDefault(); map.panBy([0, 100]);  };
document.getElementById('up').onclick = function(e)    { e.preventDefault(); map.panBy([0, -100]); };
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

This example works [fine on its own](http://bl.ocks.org/tmcw/1f707c21cf907fc7b108/da4a17bdefef00528d4c44bdc8aaaf00284c87e0).

> However, when I implemented in to my own page I got the following:

This is probably the issue. If you can provide a link to your own page, then that would help - you probably have some over-eager CSS rules that are causing this problem.

Comment: I'm using a blogger template, which may very well be the problem. Here's a test link with just the map as a post (http://maptestblog22.blogspot.com/).

Comment: And I'm not sure if this will help but I was playing around with the various templates and discovered that a different template doesn't cause the paneling or white boxes around markers. I created another test blog with that template (http://maptestblog33.blogspot.com/). Though it would seem the easiest conclusion would be to just change the template, I've unfortunately already made major updates to my initial blog and I'd prefer not to have to redo it all.